# Implement interface on Library Type in Xamarin project in C#

Tags: c#, interface, dependency-injection, xamarin

I am working on a mobile application using Xamarin. For the moment the application is only working on iOS, but the plan is to expand to other platforms. For this reason, I have a Portable Class Library (PCL) that contains the main functionality of the application, and an iOS part that contains platform specific implementation. I am using inversion of control with dependency injection to code the actual implementation in the platform projects against an interface (for example) contained in the PCL.

The actual problems is that now I need to use a `ConcurrentQueue` in the common part, but this is not availble in the PCL, so I used dependency injection in the following way in the PCL:

```
public class A
{
    ...
    public IConcurrentQueue<T> ConcurrentQueue
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    ...
}

public interface IConcurrentQueue<T>
{
    void Enqueue(T item);

    bool TryDequeue(out T result);

    int Count { get; }

    IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator();
}
```

In the platform specific code I have:

```
public class Fake<T> : ConcurrentQueue<T>, IConcurrentQueue<T>
{
    //ugly 
}

...

A.ConcurrentQueue = new Fake<ActualType>();
```

It works, but to me it seems kinda ugly to declare a "Fake" class just to use the inversion of control. In the end, in fact, `ConcurrentQueue<T>` already implements `IConcurrentQueue<T>`, even though implicitly. Is there a way to avoid creating this class?

Answer (score 0):

While this is certainly a possible scenario, if a lot of your code will use features that aren't available in the PCL, then you can use the 'Shared Code' style projects instead to get the full capabilities while still achieving the reuse you are looking for.

Comment: Actually up to now the PCL approach has been pretty good, as it was not so difficult to keep the logic of the app separated from the platform specific implementation. When this was not possible, inversion of control did the trick. In this case though, it seems a little an overkill :)

Comment: I've used both in the same project when needed to avoid overly complex stuff.  There's nothing wrong with your approach, but if you need to do it a lot, then the Shared Code might be a better fit.